# Menu in CSS using <ol>

Tags: html, css

When I hover a Media, E-sport, Community I want to see `<li>` under them. I get it with the rgb opacity. But it's a pity that when I hover AN `<li>` element which is opacity 0 it appears. I only want to do it when I hover ol li a. Someone know's the answer?

Here's my code (Menu with lists)

```css
.Menu ol {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

.Menu ol>li>ul>li>a {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Menu ol>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.Menu ol>li>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(55, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.Menu ol>li:hover>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(55, 255, 255, 1);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 205, 1);
}

.Menu ol>li>ul>li {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.Menu ol>li>ul>li {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.Menu ol>li>ul>li>a {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

Article {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 957px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Menu">

  <ol>

    <li><a href="#">Media</a>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">E-sport</a>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>

      </ul>


    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Community</a>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>

      </ul>


    </li>

  </ol>


</div>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made for you so it is a [mcve] - I changed the link color since it was invisible

Comment: The short answer is you can't really do what you want with current CSS. You can trigger the display, but one your mouse moves outside of the `a` tag the hover event will end and you will "lose" the child elements. See: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv8tg848/ If you really must trigger the display off the `a` tag you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I find the whole ".Menu ol>li:hover>ul>li>a.. " and so on pure madness, its messy and unclear, much better effects you will get when using pure divs and classes, also use display: none, so it actually takes away the elements unless you set it to something, here is the code:

Edited: Use opacity: 0 and overflow: hidden, it works with transtition

Edit2: Actually simple height: 0 + overflow hidden will give you nice transtition in AND out, it got to have fixed height on hover thou.

```
<div class="Menu">

<div class="Menu-item-container">
    <a href="#">Media</a>

    <div class="hover-items">

      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="Menu-item-container">
    <a href="#">E-sport</a>

    <div class="hover-items">

      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="Menu-item-container">
    <a href="#">Community</a>

    <div class="hover-items">

      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>

    </div>

</div>

</div>

<style>

.Menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hover-items {
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Menu-item-container {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Menu-item-container:hover .hover-items{
  height: 100px;
}

</style>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Raitar/pen/QOZgoV?editors=1100

Comment: Well I didn't use it because i can't give it transition.

Comment: Transition will work with opacity and overflow: hidden, I've edited the code

Comment: 1) I disagree with the notion that list are "pure madness" etc. Arbitrarily nested `divs` are semantically meaningless. Semantically you have a list of navigation elements so a list makes sense and provides structure. 2) All you've done is move the problem from `li` to `div`. The original question was how to trigger off the `a`.

Comment: I quess its a matter of preference, I did answer the question, check the edit, now you can hover and still have transition based on height, and hover is not triggered when hovering over class="hover-items".

Comment: You can use height + overflow in both structures you know

Comment: I guess I got caught up with the " I only want to do it when I hover ol li a". You haven't addressed that. But you have given a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Dude i'm sorry but your code is madness. why combine ol and ul.
here i give you free mine :

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.menu {
  width:100%;
  height: 33px;
  background: #000;
  position:relative;
}

.menu ul:not(.sub-menu):not(.micro){
  margin:auto;
  display:flex;
}

.menu ul li{
  position:relative;
  flex:1;
}

.menu a{
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color:#fff;
     padding: 0 15px;
}

.sub-menu{
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  transform:translateY(0);
    background: #ccc;
    transition: all 300ms;
    z-index:2;
}

.sub-menu a{
  margin:10px 0;
}

.micro{
  top:-10px;
  width:100%;
  opacity:0;
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  position: absolute;
    background: orangered;
    z-index:1;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

.micro a{
  color:#fff;
}

.menu ul li a:hover + ul.sub-menu {
 display:block;
}

.sub-menu:hover{ 
transform:translateY(5%);
 display:block;
}

.sub-menu a:hover + ul.micro {
  opacity:1;
}

.micro:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
                <ul class="micro">
                    <li><a href="#">TWITTER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TWITTER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TWITTER</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">E-SPORT</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
</ul>


</div>
```